# Made this carousel in vanilla javascript, why the img opacity stay to 1?

Tags: javascript, carousel

I'm new, very new to Javascript, and my first project was a carousel. I thought that the classic carousel would be a little problem, so I chose to do a carousel that changes opacity. The problem is that the code isn't working.

`HTML`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Carouvel</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="carousel">
        <div class="carousel_img">
            <img id="carousel_img1 defualt" src="img1.jpg" alt="">
            <img id="carousel_img2" src="img2.jpg" alt="">
            <img id="carousel_img3" src="img3.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <a id="com1" href="javascript:void(0)"><span>1</span></a>
            <a id="com2" href="javascript:void(0)"><span>2</span></a>
            <a id="com3" href="javascript:void(0)"><span>3</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

`CSS`

```
*,
*::before,
*::after
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #333;
}

.carousel
{
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

.carousel_img
{
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.carousel_img img
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

`JS`

```
const img1 = document.getElementById("carousel_img1");
const img2 = document.getElementById("carousel_img2");
const img3 = document.getElementById("carousel_img3");

const com1 = document.getElementById("com1");
const com2 = document.getElementById("com2");
const com3 = document.getElementById("com3");

let isPressed1 = false;
let isPressed2 = false;
let isPressed3 = false;

com1.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(!(isPressed1))
    {
        img1.style.opacity="1";
        isPressed1 = true
    }
});

com2.addEventListener("click", function(){

    if(isPressed1)
    {
        img1.style.opacity="0";
        isPressed1 = false;
        img2.style.opacity = "1";
        isPressed2 = true;
    }

});

com3.addEventListener("click", function(){

    if(isPressed2)
    {
        img2.style.opacity="0";
        isPressed2 = false;
        img3.style.opacity = "1";
        isPressed3 = true;
    }

});
```

Now, when I click the second button, nothing happens, like the event listener is not working. As I said before, I'm pretty new to Javascript, it's my first project. So, please don't kill me if my code isn't perfect.

Comment: You didn't peek the console. There's an error message waiting for you. `id`s must not contain white-space characters, and your script never finds the first button.

Comment: I solved the error, and now it is changing, but i have this annoying bug: it start from the third image (but it's ok), the problem is if i click the first button, it goes to the second image, and if i click the first it does not do anything. I have to click the third one again and after that if i click the first button, it shows the first image. How can i solve this

Comment: In your javascript logic, you have to press the `com1` button to turn the `isPressed1=true`, only by that you can run the second button. The simplest solution from me is to remove `if` statement and only configure style opacity of the corresponding image to the button. For the example, in the first button you want to set the first image opacity to 1 and set the rest to 0, and in the second button you want to set the second image opacity to one and the rest to 0.

Comment: I think you need entirely a different approach to this. It's possible to get your code to work, but it's a nightmare to maintain, if you want to add new images into your carousell. It's better to create a "model" of the task in JS, then control the model with an event listener. See an example at [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r265m91b/).

Comment: Also, semantically, links should not be used to change the state of a page, links are meant for navigation. You can use buttons instead, just style them to look like a link if you want. Buttons make the task even simpler, see a [fixed fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r265m91b/2/). This way you never need to update the script, just add or remove images and buttons in the markup.

Comment: Part three, [make multiple carousels](https://jsfiddle.net/ervuyx9o/) with minimum effort on the markup.